# Webpack build failing with ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: webpack

I'm having an issue with a Webpack build process that suddenly broke, resulting in the following error...

```
<s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 0/1 entries 0/0 dependencies 0/0 modules
node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:155:18)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
    at OriginalSource.updateHash (/app/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/OriginalSource.js:131:8)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:888:17)
    at handleParseResult (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:954:10)
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1048:4
    at processResult (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:763:11)
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:827:5 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
command terminated with exit code 1
```

I've tried googling `ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED webpack` which yielded almost no useful results, but it did highlight an issue using MD4 as provided by [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) (which is apparently deprecated?) to generate hashes.

The webpack.config.js code is as follows:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

/*
 * SplitChunksPlugin is enabled by default and replaced
 * deprecated CommonsChunkPlugin. It automatically identifies modules which
 * should be splitted of chunk by heuristics using module duplication count and
 * module category (i. e. node_modules). And splits the chunks…
 *
 * It is safe to remove "splitChunks" from the generated configuration
 * and was added as an educational example.
 *
 * https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/
 *
 */

/*
 * We've enabled TerserPlugin for you! This minifies your app
 * in order to load faster and run less javascript.
 *
 * https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin
 *
 */

const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/js/scripts.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        filename: 'scripts.js'
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    plugins: [new webpack.ProgressPlugin()],

    module: {
        rules: []
    },

    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],

        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    priority: -10,
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
                }
            },

            chunks: 'async',
            minChunks: 1,
            minSize: 30000,
            name: 'true'
        }
    }
};
```

How do I change the hashing algorithm used by Webpack to something else?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11562 has the details, why to downgrade NodeJs to v16.13.0

Comment: install nvm then check your node version 
use nvm list to check your node versions 
then nvm use (node version)

Comment: Downgrading to 16.13.1 worked for me

Answer (score 757):

I was able to fix it via:

```bash
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

[sachaw's comment to *Node.js v17.0.0 - Error starting project in development mode #30078*](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30078#issuecomment-947338268)

But they say they fixed it: [ijjk's comment to *Node.js v17.0.0 - Error starting project in development mode #30078*](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30078#issuecomment-948070230):

> Hi, this has been updated in v11.1.3-canary.89 of Next.js, please update and give it a try!

For me, it worked only with the annotation above.

I also want to point out that `npm run start` works with `-openssl-legacy-provider`, but `npm run dev` won't.

It seems that there is a patch:
*[Node.js 17: digital envelope routines::unsupported #14532](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532)*

I personally downgraded to `16-alpine`.

Comment: it work ! export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Comment: PowerShell: `$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"`

Comment: Where do you put: ```export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider```?

Comment: before you run your server:  `"scripts": { "debug": "NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' next dev -p 5000"`

Comment: This worked for me! Downgrading node did not work for me.

Comment: You can run all at once: `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider npm start`

Comment: It works for me in ubuntu 22.04 , rvm_ruby_version 3.0.1

Comment: Doesn't work with node `v16.14.0` for me on Fedora 36: `node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

Comment: @JasperSiepkes you need to use node 17 or newer. On fedora, you can install it using modules https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/modularity/using-modules/

Comment: fixed the issue

Comment: This woked for me NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider npm run serve

Comment: added to windows environment variables and it helped for v18.12.1. Thanks)

Comment: On windows with react, edit package.json ```json { "scripts": { "start": "set \"NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider\" && react-scripts start"}} ```

Comment: `start: "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\" --openssl-legacy-provider\" npm start" `

Comment: You can add this to ~/.zshrc on mac and it will run every time you run npm start

Comment: All these solutions regarding downgrading or using unsafe options are hacky... 16 is out of LTS in a month and Node 18 will not support these strategies (even if they do work) they should be strongly discouraged given that they're making your app more vulnerable per OpenSSL's definitions.

Comment: this works, but visual code can not start with NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Comment: It works. I did not have a idea where to put this... but after searching NODE_OPTIONS, it found match in the `package.json` as command options for npm start. problem solved!

Answer (score 185):

I had this problem too. I'd accidentally been running on the latest Node.js (17.0 at time of writing), not the LTS version (14.18) which I'd meant to install. Downgrading my Node.js install to the LTS version fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Same here. Downgrading to 16.x worked as well. Its LTS start in a week (2021-10-26) according to https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/ so I went for that.

Comment: I am having this problem with v16.13.0.

Comment: Thanks. It worked here. I used 'asdf' to run the LTS version locally inside the project.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11562 has the details, why to downgrade NodeJs to v16.13.0

Comment: @Trip check your package.json for ReactNative. Ask a question.

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena We do not use React, and ReactNative does not appear anywhere in our package-lock.json.

Comment: @Trip Okay, [Note: it's package.json and not package-lock.json] I used this solution for ReactNative and saw that it favoured people using ReactJS (web development) as well, so I was curious. I think you can ask a separate question specifying the platform you are using.

Comment: Confirm downgrade from v17.2.0 to v16.13.1 is working fine

Comment: Confirm - downgrading Node solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Node Version Manager via [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) works excellent for switching effortlessly between versions

Comment: Before following suggestions that open your app to security vulnerabilities, please see answer to same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/1072629

In the best world scenario, find the right fix for the issue instead of hacking in a solution. It may work, but that doesnt mean it is right

Comment: You saved my day, after uninstall Nodejs and intall nodejs LTS + npm update in console visual studio it's perfectly worked :D

Answer (score 82):

It is not my answer really, but I found this workaround /hack/ to fix my problem [Code Check in for a GitHub project](https://github.com/cockpit-project/starter-kit/commit/3220617fec508aabbbc226a87a165c21fb72e913)... see the bug comments [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13572#issuecomment-923736472).

I ran into ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED after updating with **npm install**.

I added the following to node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);
```

I tried [Ryan Brownell's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported/69394785#69394785) and ended up with a different error, but this worked...

---

Typescript equivalent:

```js
import crypto from "crypto";

const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
Object.assign(crypto, {
  createHash: (algorithm: string): crypto.Hash => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm === "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm),
});
```

Comment: This worked fine for me in Webpack4. I'm bouncing between 12LTS / 17 and this is a big time saver.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2021. Thank you for describing the folder location of the file as well. It solved my issue. I had previously tried the solution that exports variables to the environment and it caused VSCode to no longer load. So this solves it without globally compromising other programs.

Comment: So we have to add the code when `react-scripts` - now 3.0.1 or 3.4.4 - gets a newer Version?

Comment: It's also working in the app's own config/webpack.config.js file, so great solution!

Comment: Finally a solution that actually works, doesn't leave us vulnerable, and doesn't assume a specific project setup (this can go in the main projects config file). Thank you!

Comment: this worked for me: `const crypto = require("crypto");
const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);`

Answer (score 67):

[Ryan Brownell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported/69394785#69394785) is the ideal solution if you are using Webpack v5.54.0+.

If you're using an older version of Webpack, you can still solve this by changing the hash function to one that is not deprecated. (It [defaults to the ancient `md4`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputhashfunction), which OpenSSL has removed support for, which is the root cause of the error.) The supported algorithms are any supported by [crypto.createHash](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options). For example, to use [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2):

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        hashFunction: "sha256"
    }
};
```

Finally, if you are unable to change the Webpack configuration (e.g., if it's a transitive dependency which is running Webpack), you can enable OpenSSL's [legacy provider](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Providers) to temporarily enable MD4 during the Webpack build. This is a last resort. Create a file `openssl.cnf` with this content…

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect

[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect

[default_sect]
activate = 1

[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

…and then set the environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` to the path to that file when running Webpack.

Comment: Turns out that the `hashFunction` fix can help. but it might be insufficient: the ConcatenatedModule optimizer in Webpack 4.x [hardcodes the use of MD4](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/3956274f1eada621e105208dcab4608883cdfdb2/lib/optimize/ConcatenatedModule.js#L563), so if your build process uses it, you might need to go the `openssl.cnf` route. I think this might be the general case for Vue CLI 4.x projects.

Answer (score 65):

There is a hashing algorithm that comes with Webpack v5.54.0+ that does not rely on OpenSSL.

To use this hash function that relies on a npm-provided dependency instead of an operating system-provided dependency, modify the webpack.config.cjs `output` key to include the `hashFunction: "xxhash64"` option.

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        hashFunction: "xxhash64"
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error: Digest method not supported`

Comment: agree. webpack upgrade fixed the issue for me. I was using react 17, then upgraded to react 18 which did bring me webpack 5.74.0 => problem solved.

Comment: If you still get this error on webpack 5.54+ and node 17+, look at your stack trace. In my case, `babel-loader: 8.2.2` was also using a deprecated hashing function. Upgrading to `babel-loader: 8.3.0` fixed the issue.

Comment: I had the same scenario as @bendytree. Turns out I didn't even need to use the `hashFunction` webpack configuration at all. Upgrading to `babel-loader: 8.3.0` solved the issue. Looks like it was actually fixed in 8.2.4: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/releases/tag/v8.2.4.

Comment: xxhash64 is also now gone... you can try a different variant of this by switching hashFunction to: "sha256"... but I still had issues in the next layer down (possibly because of harcoded usage of md4).

Answer (score 27):

This error is mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V17.md#17.0.0) for Node.js 17.0.0, with a suggested workaround:

> If you hit an **ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED** error in your application with Node.js 17, it’s likely that your application or a module you’re using is attempting to use an algorithm or key size which is no longer allowed by default with OpenSSL 3.0. A command-line option, **--openssl-legacy-provider**, has been added to revert to the legacy provider as a temporary workaround for these tightened restrictions.

Comment: I didnt work here. :(

--openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Comment: @Cesarvspr you have to add it to the env var, not as an argument to `npm` command.
`NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' npm run build`

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I figured this out after some research

Answer (score 23):

I faced the same challenge, but you just need to downgrade Node.js to version 16.13 and everything works well. Download LTS, not the current on *[Downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)*.

Comment: This works.. I just used 'n' to update to lts and it started working for me

Comment: Worked for 16.20.0 LTS for my Angular project. :)

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this issue using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) (Webpack) and was able to fix it within file *package.json* by adding in the `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` (referenced in [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported/69746937#69746937)) to the beginning of the script:

***`package.json`:***

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider  node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Try upgrading your Webpack version to 5.62.2.

Comment: This should be accepted, upgrading WebPack solved the issue for me. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm on webpack 5.81.0, still have this issue

Comment: This didn't work for me. Updated my webpack to mentioned version but didn't work. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same problem in a project I developed with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/). For the solution, I ran the project as follows and I solved the problem.

```
cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' next dev
```

Comment: For those using Vue 2 
you can simply add `NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider'`
don't include  `cross-env`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with my [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) project and I solved it.

#### macOS and Linux

1. You should have installed [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (Node Version Manager). If you never had before, just run this command in your terminal:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash`

2. Open your project
3. Open the terminal in your project
4. Run the command `nvm install 16.13.0` or any older version
5. After the installation is completed, run `nvm use 16.13.0`

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, just a workaround.

Comment: @emendelski Then, whats the solution?

Comment: Check all the other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69746937/3585513, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476335/3585513.

Answer (score 4):

This means that you have the latest Node.js version. If you are using it for [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) then you need to change the image from

```
FROM node
```

to

```
FROM node:14
```

Comment: downgrading whole node shouldnt be considered as good practice

Comment: With Node Version Manager (nvm) globally installed try $ nvm use 14