# Why npm run serve is throwing ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED?

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

The following is my output. My Vue CLI version is 4.5.14.

```
PS C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project> npm run serve

> modal-project@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve    

 INFO  Starting development server...
10% building 2/4 modules 2 active C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\hot\dev-server.jsError: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
10% building 2/5 modules 3 active ...ments\James\modal-project\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\src\main.js n
ode:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at C:\Users\Dell\Documents\James\modal-project\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: You should add more information about your setup. Is this a fresh vue setup, do you have some libs already installed etc. Also: What is your node version?

Comment: this is fresh vue setup. I am beginner. my node is v17.0.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack build failing with ERR\_OSSL\_EVP\_UNSUPPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported)

Comment: Do not use odd Node versions, unless you know what you're doing. The latest stable is 16.

Comment: The "duplicate" does in fact not answer the question which is specific to Vue. There is no `webpack.config.js`.