# Why i don't npm run serve for vue

Tags: vue.js

E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo>npm run serve

> demo@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...
10% building 2/4 modules 2 active ...\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://192.168.1.46:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-nodeError: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
at module.exports (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
at runSyncOrAsync (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
at Array. (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
at Storage.finished (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
10% building 2/5 modules 3 active ...emo\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js??ref--14-0!E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\src\main.jsnode:internal/crypto/hash:67
this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
at module.exports (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at Array. (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
at Storage.finished (E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
at E:\HOC\HK3\Vue\demo\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.2.0

Comment: try installing nvm and try with a lower version of node.js ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported

Here a similar issue has been discussed