# How to change the hash function in webpack-config.js when using create-expo-app?

Tags: node.js, react-native, webpack, expo

Following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73465262/13176156

I tried the two options given in the answer, but they both did not work. I installed @expo\webpack-config and implemented the changes within the webpack-config.js file as shown below.

The first, changing output.hashFunction to use 'xxhash64', complained about a missing digest method.

> Error: Digest method not supported

Setting experiments.futureDefaults = true gave this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'futureDefaults')

If anyone could help me understand why its not working and if anything can be done to use the alternate hashing algorithm that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);

  // Customize the config before returning it.
  config.output.hashFunction = 'xxhash64';
  config.experiments.futureDefaults = true;
  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `xxhash-addon` for your Node.js runtime.

The implementation of its `XXHash64` class satisfies the interface requirements (object must have update/digest methods) for a custom `hashFunction` required by Webpack.

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);

  // Customize the config before returning it.
  config.output.hashFunction = require('xxhash-addon').XXHash64;
  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

If that does not work you can edit your `webpack-config.js` and add these lines with your hash function of choice:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md4" ? "sha256" : algorithm);
```

Useful when needing to revert to a legacy algo (OpenSSL / potentially less secure one) to temporarily address any compatibility issues.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69691525/3426192