# Nuxt2 doesn't work with latest LTS of node (v18)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I'm newbie and this my first vuejs project using nuxt.
I running command by "npm run dev" in CMD, after run command "npm install" for my project and got this:

```
* Client █████████████████████████ building (10%) 1/2 modules 1 active
 node_modules\webpack-hot-middleware\client.js

* Server █████████████████████████ building (10%) 1/1 modules 0 active


node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^ttp://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)                                        07:49:12
    at module.exports (C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)                                                              07:49:12
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\a\revampkiriminaja\kiriminaja\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

PS: I am able to `run serve` and get a working `localhost:3000` in my browser.

Comment: More context is highly welcome to help you debug this further.

Comment: Please check which version of Node are you using... Simmilar problem found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported

Comment: Thanks for responding my question. I've checked nodejs, nuxt and npm version : Node.js v18.12.1, Nuxt @ v2.15.8, npm --version 8.19.2. Am I have to downgrade nodejs, and what the best choice for nuxtjs version? thanks for your help sir

Comment: Not sure that Nuxt2 is able to run perfectly at Node 18. Try 16 rather. You can also use yarn to maybe have something more verbose.

Comment: Thank you. I've just successfully running my nuxtjs project on localhost:3000 by your recommendation.

Comment: for others developer who have the same issue, this might be able to do. 1) uninstall latest nodejs 2) install nodejs specific version (v16.0.0) to use nuxtjs 3) use yarn install then yarn run dev instead npm to have something more verbose. :))

Comment: I've posted my answer.

Comment: Here is the low down on the actual reason for the error message : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027407/11596811

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP solved the issue by using Node `v16`, I recommend to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for such purpose btw.
[The LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/) aka Node.js `v18` seems to be too new for Nuxt2.

PS: using yarn or PNPM will give more verbose feedback overall as of what is happening during your packages installation.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the issues related to ssl or 'digital envelope routines' are fixed in more recent nuxt 2 releases.
Try 2.17.1.
Everything works for me, even on Node v20.

Comment: You should not use Nuxt2 anymore tho, since the EOL for Vue2 is the end of 2023.