# i face this issue while running yarn start in react native app in monorepo architecture

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at stableHash (/Users/---node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
    at JsTransformer.getCacheKey (/Users/---node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:478:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/-----node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer/getTransformCacheKey.js:39:29)
    at new Transformer (/Users/----/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:147:28)
    at /Users/-----node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:54:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69746937/3667121

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)