# Node.js openssl error while runing the npm start commmand

Tags: node.js, openssl

I am new to node.js and i was trying to make a interactive website for my CNN Project but got this error. help me out guys

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\Potato-disease-Major-1\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

i tried reinntalling the modules, but got the same result

Comment: I think the issue here is the versioning of `OpenSSL`. Try downgrading your node or upgrading openssl packages and see if that solves the issue

Comment: @Cerlin: not really. First, nodejs on Windows uses its own copy of OpenSSL because there is usually no system-supplied one. Second, this error is caused because _newer_ OpenSSL (3.0.0 up) has disabled some obsolete and broken or unsafe algorithms, inluding webpack's default MD4. Unless you downgrade to old nodejs _and_ old OpenSSL, you need to either change webpack to use a decent hash or use the nodejs option `--openssl-legacy-provider`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/ and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75504981/