# Angular app runs fine on my machine but after I build a Docker image it gives me "ERROR [node 6/6] RUN npm run build --prod" error

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, dockerfile

Here is my DockerFile. I also have .dockerignore with (node_modules; .gitignore).

```
#stage 1
FROM node:alpine as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install 
#RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.29
RUN npm run build --prod

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@material/dialog": "^6.0.0",
    "@material/snackbar": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I tried almost everything and went through many threads here but had NO luck :(
The CODE works fine on my Machine without any WARN or Error. But After I run docker build to dockerize it:

```
docker build -t name/app_frontend:latest .
```

It gives an Error. Here is the complete execution with error:

```
[+] Building 200.0s (14/15)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 358B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                                                                                    3.4s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                                                                                                                                     3.4s 
 => [auth] library/nginx:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 21.13kB                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [node 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:alpine@sha256:667dc6ed8fc6623ccd21cb5fa355c90f848daaf5d6df96bc940869bfdf91c19a                                                                          0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:6f94b7f4208b5d5391246c83a96246ca204f15eaf7e636cefda4e6348c8f6101                                                               0.0s 
 => CACHED [node 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [node 3/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                            0.1s 
 => [node 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                   180.7s 
 => [node 5/6] RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.29                                                                                                                                              6.7s 
 => ERROR [node 6/6] RUN npm run build --prod                                                                                                                                                      9.0s 
------
 > [node 6/6] RUN npm run build --prod:
#14 0.780 npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
#14 0.794
#14 0.794 > frontend@0.0.0 build
#14 0.794 > ng build
#14 0.794
#14 8.969 node:internal/crypto/hash:71
#14 8.969   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
#14 8.969                   ^
#14 8.969
#14 8.969 Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
#14 8.969     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
#14 8.969     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
#14 8.969     at module.exports (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
#14 8.969     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:412:16)
#14 8.969     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:444:10
#14 8.969     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:320:13
#14 8.969     at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
#14 8.969     at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:203:19
#14 8.969     at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (/app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/virtual_file_system_decorator.js:46:13)
#14 8.969     at processResource (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
#14 8.969     at iteratePitchingLoaders (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
#14 8.969     at runLoaders (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
#14 8.969     at NormalModule.doBuild (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:292:3)
#14 8.969     at NormalModule.build (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:438:15)
#14 8.969     at Compilation.buildModule (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:702:10)
#14 8.969     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:944:14 {
#14 8.969   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
#14 8.969   library: 'digital envelope routines',
#14 8.969   reason: 'unsupported',
#14 8.969   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
#14 8.969 }
#14 8.969
#14 8.969 Node.js v19.7.0
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build --prod]: exit code: 1**
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of Node in both environments? That is, your container seems to be running `19.7.0`, are you running the same version on your dev machine? You can check with command: `node -v`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack build failing with ERR\_OSSL\_EVP\_UNSUPPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported)

Comment: My Node.js version is: v16.16.0. Do you think this is the issue?

Comment: yes, this is most probably the issue.

Comment: Great, Thanks by replacing this `FROM node:16-alpine3.16 as node` in dockerfile solved it.

Comment: Added as an answer so people don't need to read through the comments to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most probably running into issues with unmatching node versions.

As per your post, you're container is running node version `19.7.0`. You should check to make sure that your development machine, where the code is known to work, is actually using the same version.

You can check this by running `node -v` in your preferred terminal.

If the versions do not match, you'll want to upgrade/downgrade your container image so that it uses the matching version of node.

For example, for node 16, you can change your docker file to read `FROM node:16-alpine3.16 as node`.

For node 14 you would replace it with: `FROM node:14-alpine3.16 as node`

You can find the official image versions available [here.](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)