# how to fix Angular error opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086 code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

i am making changes my Angular app after a long time and getting this error. I have done npm install post that ng serve. and getting this error.

opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

Comment: Angular only supports LTS versions of node (only the odd versions). So v19 is not supported.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The node version is 18.5 now still not able to run the project

Answer (score 4):

Open your command prompt / terminal and run the following command:

Windows users

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Mac users

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

**OR**

**`Downgrade node version`**

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of NodeJS being v17 or later.

You will need to follow the following steps:

- Uninstall your current NodeJS version
- Install NodeJS v16 (https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.19.1/)
- Run Angular as usual

If you want to run it with NodeJS > v16 then upgrade your Angular application first to the latest version and install the current NodeJS LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Set the following environment variable in the shell before running Angular CLI:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69746937)

Answer (score 1):

If your app is dockerized you can use these 2 lines in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider --no-experimental-fetch" 
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=$NODE_OPTIONS && ng build
```