# Electron - Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm having some trouble with my electron app. I'm running node 18.12.1 and to make things working I've installed node 16 as a dependency of my project. If I use node 16 the `npm run electron:serve` all will work fine, I've tried to uninstall it to use my system node version, but I will get this error. I've searched here and I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported/69746937#69746937), but I'm unable to force node to bypass the openssl hash system.

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5    
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12   
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\...\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Is there a way to fix this on node 18?