# How to solve 'digital envelope routines::unsupported' error in Node.js and Vue.js with PrimeVue template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, primevue

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at Array. (D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
at Storage.finished (D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
at D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
at D:\workspace\mulsan-admin\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.0

**HOW TO SOLVE THIS ERROR ?**

`npm update`

latest node version support primevue template

Comment: The question lacks the details, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . The error is most likely caused by Node version that is incompatible with this project, or vice versa. Make sure you stick to even versions. If you can verify you use 18 then you can try to downgrade to 16

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394632/webpack-build-failing-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.