# I get an error when starting the React app

Tags: reactjs

I get this error on npm start, on a new React app. Can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue06G.jpg)

```
npm install 

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\react-app-polyfill\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-typescript@9.0.0 requires a peer of @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^3.6.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
ch":"x64"})

added 2261 packages from 982 contributors and audited 2269 packages in 46.662s

140 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 431 vulnerabilities (4 low, 193 moderate, 201 high, 33 critical)
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)     
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)     
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)      
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)    
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\niki8\source\repos\LendIt\8.1.0\reactjs\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs@4.7.1 start: `craco start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs@4.7.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\niki8\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-27T10_51_36_851Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Usual stuff.. Clear npm Cache

`npm cache clean -f`

Delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file from your project directory.Run npm install again to reinstall the packages.

The warning about `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript` suggests that you might need to install peer dependencies manually.

`npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^3.6.1 --save-dev`

Reinstall Project Dependencies. Go to your project directory and run `npm install`

Try starting your project again

Comment: This fix the problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778087/17766774.